# remove blank pages from ClassicThesis

Tags: lyx, classicthesis, blank-page

I am using ClassicThesis in LyX.

I have problems with the autogeneration of blank pages in the template. At the moment a blank page is inserted infront of a chapter if the chapter would have started on an even page (like a book). Does anybody know how to change the classicthesis-config.tex file to prevent this insertion of blank pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `openany` class option:

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}

\end{document}
```