# Classicthesis - Remove blank pages

Tags: classicthesis, blank-page

I am using ClassicThesis in LyX to write my thesis. Unfortunately, my University has a rather large number of inane formatting requirements that force me to change portions of ClassicThesis (defeating the entire point of using it in the first place, but sadly I have no choice).

Apparently my university is unaware that theses are generally published as books, as one such requirement is the removal of ALL blank pages from the document. This includes the blank pages before and after each 'Part' label and after Chapters to ensure the next chapter starts on the right.

I have attempted to search for how to do this, and found previous topics on this subject:

[Removing blank pages around "Parts" in Classicthesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288792/removing-blank-pages-around-parts-in-classicthesis)

[remove blank pages from ClassicThesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131739/remove-blank-pages-from-classicthesis?rq=1)

Using 'openany' is the most freuently suggested solution, but I have been completely unable to implement it. I have attempted to edit 'classicthesis.layout' to the following:

```
# predefined class options (the class is scrreprt from KOMA Script), all can be overridden
ClassOptions
  Other     "fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,oneside,openany,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,BCOR=5mm,footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty"
  PageStyle ""
  FontSize  ""
End
```

I have changed 'twoside' to 'oneside' and specified 'openany' - however, this has no effect on the document. I have limited experience with latex; I would greatly appreciate an explanation of how to remove the blank pages, and why what I am currently doing is not working.

Thank you!

Edit

For anyone with a similar problem looking at this in the future, I was able to solve this by inserting the following code around each element that had blank pages

```
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax

\endgroup
```

This requires inserting line breaks manually, but is effective. In LyX, put the above code in an ERT block bracketing places where you want pages removed.

Despite my (somewhat gimmicky) success, I still do not understand why what I attempted in the original question did not work.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen how would I go about changing the definition? This does sounds promising, can you describe it in a bit more detail? Thanks!

Comment: off topic: (i) so far I didn't see a thesis divided onto parts (thesis is not novel or text book ...), (ii) with option `oneside` you don't need option `openany` because in this case the text is only in right side of thesis (book), with option `twoside` and `openany` you make request to LaTeX to start chapters immediately after and of previous one regardless if it start on even or odd page. If I corectly understand your question,  you this combination of option is what you looking for.

Comment: @Zarko - Unfortunately changing these options appears to have had no effect on the document. I tried 'twoside' with 'openany' and 'oneside' by its self, but neither option had an effect. I still have a blank page before and after reach part (if needed, I will remove the parts) and two blank pages before each Chapter starts.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen - I added renewcommand\cleardoublepage{\clearpage} to my preamble (in LyX) as you suggested, but this also had no effect. Did I need to do anything else? Thanks for your help, and sorry about no minimum working example - Classicthesis is complicated and I'm not sure how I would create one without uploading a bunch of files.

Comment: Then is time to show your code.  Short as possible which cause your problem. Seems that you have somewhere hard coded this features.

Comment: @Zarko I tried to create a minimum working example, but actually have not been able to recreate the problem. The only difference I can think of is that my thesis uses child documents, while the example I created does not - otherwise they are identical, same preamble and .sty files. Do you know what in the child document could be interfering?

Comment: how you include child document into main? if you use `include{<child name>}`, for test tray to replace it with`input{<child name>}`.

Comment: @zarko & MarcvanDongen - I figured out a work around for what I need to do (see edited post). I still don't understand exactly what is going on, and I think if I ever have another project like this I would probably use LaTeX from the beginning and skip LyX - much easier to fiddle with stuff.

I really appreciate the time both of you took to help me out - thanks!

Comment: off topic: but the university requirements with which I've had the pleasure to come into contact require theses be printed and bound **single sided**. This makes the requirement of not having "blank pages" very sensible indeed.

Comment: Adding `oneside` to LyX>Document settings>Document Class>Custom removed all blank pages for me. No need to change the .layout file.

Comment: I am interested. Why don't you hae a choice concerning classicthesis?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue where no other suggestions like `openany`, `oneside`, `clearpage`, etc. worked. At first your method did not work either, but I had to include the blank line before the last line (`\endgroup`) for it to work. Just thought I'd leave this comment to help anyone else in the future.